# negatives in a stack while looping through it

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to write a function which tells the user the number of negative numbers in a stack. I am stuck with the following below and I have not been able to get the correct answer so far. I've tested it with several test stacks. I think the problem is due to how the loops are placed. Any help will be appreciated!

```
int negcount = 0;
for(int i=0; i<mystack.size(); i++) {

    if(mystack.top() < 0) {
        negcount++;
        mystack.pop();
    }else {
        mystack.pop();
    }
}
return negcount;
```

Comment: Since you're not using i at all, just use while(mystack.size() > 0). Are you sure you're meant to be mutating the stack?

Comment: I don't think for is the best way to loop through a collection that you are modifying. Some statements in that if/else are a bit redundant. I'm not sure if pop() returns the element from the stack, but if it does, you could do sth like this:

while(mystack.size() > 0)
{
  int x = mystack().pop();
  if (x < 0) negcount++;
}
return negcount;

Comment: is your stack.size() give correct size of stack

Comment: In both the cases you need `mystack.pop();` so put it outside the condition to save LOC

Comment: The problem with your code is eventually i is going to catch up to the none zero size. If stack size = 10, it will pop 5 times before reaching i, leaving the bottom 5 items in the stack unaccounted for. To solve this, add i-- to the bottom of your loop, or do the obvious and change it to while( mystack.size() > 0 ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong, because every time you pop an item from stack. here is what would work for you:

```
    int negcount = 0;
            while(mystack.size()>0) {

                    if(mystack.top() < 0) {
                            negcount++;
                            mystack.pop();                      
                    }else {             
                            mystack.pop();
                    }
           }
   return negcount;
```

Comment: You're right, I was not doing the looping correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think for is the best way to loop through a collection that you are modifying. Some statements in that if/else are a bit redundant. I'm not too familiar with C++, but you could do sth like this:

```
while(mystack.size() > 0) 
{ 
     if (mystack.top() < 0) negcount++;
     mystack.pop();
} 
return negcount;
```

Comment: -1: In C++, pop() does *not* return anything, due to exception safety.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about that but I took a leap of faith :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I've actually never used a stack in C++ yet, so that's new to me too. Useful thing to know before (if) I ever need to use a stack.